# Google-maps plugin in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am interested in integrating google-maps api with my grails application. I have been searching for a plugin for doing that more comfortably but I didn't find anything under grails.org/plugins

I found another option on github https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Google-Map-Plugin but I tried it and It seems not work with grails 2.0.3

Could anyone recommends me another option or alternative?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look at:

- http://grails.org/plugin/richui#Map
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails05208/index.html
- http://www.componentix.com/blog/2/twitter-and-google-maps-mashup-in-minutes-with-grails